# Is there a way to change url of repository in github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a base repository for the site (`user.github.io`) and a repository "repo" that acts like a page (`user.github.io/repo/`). Is there a way to change the url of the page to `user.github.io/r/` without changing the name of the repository?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need a separate project page for `repo`, you could do the following:

1. Create a directory `r` in the `user/user.github.io` repository.
2. Move your web page files from `user/repo` to this directory.